# Getting error running ansible playbook to create environment on openstack

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run an ansible playbook. The playbook simply creates a new server in openstack environment. I have tried the playbook on another instance and loads of times before and the playbook works but it would simply not work on my current environment.

When i execute the playbook i get this error:

```
TASK [Create vm for "{{jfmc_log_environements}}" in zhr] ***********************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "openstacksdk is required for this module"}

Ansible Command i am running is

ansible-playbook --vault-id playbooks/test/vaultpassword -i inventories/inventory playbooks/jfmc_vm_create.yaml --e groupe=test
```

Now i have double checked that openstacksdk is installed. Python version is also fine 2.7.5. Ansible version running is 2.7.5

When I run pip install openstacksdk it says requirement already satisfied in bunch of lines.

How shall i proceed?

Comment: "When I run pip install openstacksdk it says requirement already satisfied in bunch of lines."  It probably says a lot of things, but I'm guessing one of them is an error installing `openstacksdk`, or you're using virtual python environments of some kind and it's installed in the wrong one

Answer (score 2):

When both python2 and python3 installed on a system then this issue occurs. To resolve this issue add following line in

> ansible.cfg

file under

> [defaults]

section.

> interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python3

The modified file should look something like this.

```
 [defaults] 
 interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install --upgrade decorator`

Long story is I was facing

```
The full traceback is:
WARNING: The below traceback may *not* be related to the actual failure.
  File "/tmp/ansible_os_server_facts_payload_2j5saA/ansible_os_server_facts_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/openstack.py", line 116, in openstack_cloud_from_module
    sdk = importlib.import_module('openstack')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openstack/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    import openstack.connection
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openstack/connection.py", line 166, in <module>
    from openstack.cloud import openstackcloud as _cloud
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openstack/cloud/openstackcloud.py", line 35, in <module>
    import dogpile.cache
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dogpile/cache/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .region import CacheRegion, register_backend, make_region  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dogpile/cache/region.py", line 15, in <module>
    from decorator import decorate

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "api_timeout": null, 
            "auth": null, 
            "auth_type": null, 
            "availability_zone": null, 
            "cacert": null, 
            "cert": null, 
            "cloud": null, 
            "detailed": null, 
            "interface": "public", 
            "key": null, 
            "region_name": null, 
            "server": "slave-test-merrn-1", 
            "timeout": 180, 
            "verify": null, 
            "wait": true
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "openstacksdk is required for this module"
}
```

Based on ideas from [1] I tried to upgrade decorator module. As it seems to be in fact problem of old decorator module. Error message is misleading. This solution is apparently just workaround. And there is problem somewhere else.

```
pip install --upgrade decorator
Collecting decorator
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/cd/7c8240007e9716b14679bc217a1baefa4432aa30394f7e2ec40a52b1a708/decorator-4.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: decorator
  Found existing installation: decorator 3.4.0
    Uninstalling decorator-3.4.0:
      Successfully uninstalled decorator-3.4.0
Successfully installed decorator-4.3.2
```

[1] https://github.com/oasis-origin/oasis-pipeline/issues/1